# How to enter a character to QLineEdits from QPushButtons depending on the focus in Qt

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt4, qlineedit, qpushbutton

I am using Qt Creator to make a UI.
UI consists of two or more `QLineEdit`s and ten `QPushButton`s to input 0-9 numberic characters to `QLineEdit`s. How can I enter 0-9 number `string`s in both `QLineEdit`s one by one.

If I press `QPushButton` with label '5'and cursor is on `QLineEdit` (say `QLineEdit` 1) it should append '5' in `QLineEdit` 1 or if `QLineEdit` 2 is selected it should append '5' in `QLineEdit` 2 and respectively with the other `QPushButton`s also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could have a `slot` in your ui class like the following

```
void MyDialog::numberButtonPressed()
{
    QPushButton* btn = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(QObject::sender());
    if (!btn)
        return; // TODO error handling
    ui.lineEdit->setText(ui.lineEdit->text() + btn->text());
}
```

and then `QObject::connect` all numeric buttons to that `slot`.

cheers

Comment: To complete your answer: check which QLineEdit has focus to change its text: `QLineEdit* lineEdit = ui.lineEdit->hasFocus() ? ui.lineEdit : ui.lineEdit2 ; lineEdit->setText(lineEdit->text() + btn->text())`

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am unable to interpret your answers properly can  you please elaborate. Please make sure I am working on QT Creator

Answer (score 0):

In QT Creator after adding pushbutton to slots in UI, go to function and check if it has focus or not with hasFocus().

e.g.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if(ui->lineEdit_1->hasFocus)
    {
        ui->lineEdit_1->setText("your text");
    }
    else if(ui->lineEdit_2->hasFocus)
    {
        ui->lineEdit_2->setText("your text");
    }
}
```